# add Drupal subform

Tags: 7

I have a question in drupal I want to make a content type that have a title and body and a subform that contain a title and image and video and date and I can add more than one subform I have searched for this module but I didn't find any so I tried making a custom modules using field hooks API but I face problem My site does not work again I don't no if I have an error or not but there is no syntax error at all but after adding my field and saving data the site does not work

Does any one have a good tutorial for that Hope you can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.  With Field Collection you can add fields like title, picture and video into a collection then you add the collection in the principal form.

Comment: did you try it it make errors  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file_field_widget_submit() (line 754)

Comment: What is the version of drupal, coolection field and CCK that are you using?

Comment: drupal 7.10 and drupal core cck

Comment: thanks,I found a solution of my problem @ http://drupal.org/node/1329856